# Get environment variables of a running process

Tags: linux

Where or how can I get the environment variables of a running process?

Consider the case that I'm neither root nor the user that started the process.

Comment: ... you don't ?

Comment: If you started the process or if you are root you can obtain the variables with `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/PID_OF_PROC/environ`. If you don't, then it's by design that you are not allowed to see them because they may contain sensitive data

Comment: `strings /proc/$PID/environ`